# XML special characters

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, xml

I am doing a catalog layout in indesign using xml. Is there a special character in xml for column break similar to `&#09;` for tab characters or are column break characters just an Indesign feature?

Comment: No there isn't. See this document for an exhaustive listing of possibly recognised meta characters : http://www.indiscripts.com/blog/public/data/idcs4-special-characters/en_InDesignCS4-CS5-SpecialChars.pdf

Comment: Thank for the link. What a handy document.

What does unicode look like in xml? I tried &#'unicode'; and that didn't work.

Comment: I was mainly meaning to ensure the encoding of the XML file is set to UTF-8.See xml declaration for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The `&#09;`  is a code by ASCII (American Standard Code for Information Interchange).

Apart from the invisible ASCII control characters (the ones you can't type), all other characters are just normal text. Currency signs (€, £, $, ƒ, ₨, Ƀ, and others), all the punctuation (except < and &), and all other letters, signs, and symbols in any language or writing system are just text (assuming you have the correct character encoding).

You need to set the correct character encoding into your XML file.